# Creating GeoServer layers from GeoJSON generated by PHP script

Tags: geoserver, php

I have few layers on my map rendered with ol.format.GeoJSON. I  generated GeoJSON from pgsql database with PHP scripts. The size of layers ranges from 1MB to 5MB so to speed up the process I want to use GeoServer. Is there a way or library in PHP that can send generated GeoJSON to GeoServer and create layer which I will then render as WMS?

Comment: have you looked at wfs-t or the GeoServer REST API?

Comment: If the source of the data is originally PostgreSQL, why not just link GeoServer to PostgreSQL, and configure a WMS on top of that (no need for GeoJSON)